# Exclude path from RewriteRule using RewriteCond in Apache2

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I have Apache server version `2.4.18 (Ubuntu)`.

I have conditional `RewriteRule` that applies to most parts of my site. I want to exclude paths starting with `/norewrite` from that rewrite.

The rewrite looks like this:

```
RewriteCond <condition 1>
RewriteCond <condition 2>
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://example.com [L]
```

I tried to exclude `/norewrite` with following:

```
RewriteCond <condition 1>
RewriteCond <condition 2>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/norewrite
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://example.com [L]
```

I have also tried different syntaxes such as `!/norewrite`, `!norewrite` and `!^\/norewrite` but with all these the addresses starting with `/norewrite` still get rewriten when the 2 other conditions are true.

After reading Apache docs for `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` I belive that this should work. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have an `OR` flag on the preceding condition? The directives you have posted are perhaps over exemplified, please include your actual directives where possible. The directives you posted would trigger a 302 redirect, not a rewrite, as you seem to imply. (The _susbstitution_ string is not strictly correct either - but maybe that's just your example?) You also don't need an additional _condition_ if you are excluding a single URL path (but the conditions are arguably in the wrong order anyway).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exemplified code in your question looks OK in itself, providing:

- You do not have an `OR` flag on the preceding *condition* that would make the next condition (that excludes the specific URL-path) optional.
- These directives are sufficiently early in your config so as to avoid conflicts with other mod_rewrite directives. Note that the `REQUEST_URI` server variable is updated in-place if you have earlier directives that rewrite the URL.
- There are no conflicting mod_alias `Redirect` or `RedirectMatch` directives that are overriding these mod_rewrite directives. Note that the *order* does not matter; the mod_alias directives will execute regardless.

> ```
> RewriteCond <condition 1>
> RewriteCond <condition 2>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/norewrite
> RewriteRule ^.*$ https://example.com [L]
> ```

Note that by specifying an absolute URL (scheme + hostname) in the `RewriteRule` *substitution* this will implicitly trigger a 302 (temporary) *external redirect*, not a "rewrite" as you seem to imply. If this should be a "redirect", then you should be explicit and include the `R` flag - more readable and avoids potential bugs going forward.

Minor point, but you are also missing the trailing slash on the end of the absolute URL (*substitution* string). If you omit it then you are reliant on the user-agent appending the slash in the redirected request (all major browsers should do this).

If you only want to exclude a single URL-path then you don't need a separate condition. And since you are not currently doing anything with the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, it is more efficient to perform this check in the `RewriteRule` instead.

For example:

```
RewriteCond <condition 1>
RewriteCond <condition 2>
RewriteRule !^/?norewrite https://example.com/ [R=302,L]
```

NB: The last `RewriteCond` should never have an `OR` flag, otherwise the rule will execute unconditionally. (It's essentially treated like `... OR true`.)

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* is processed first, so the above states that for all URL-paths that do not start `/norewrite` then `<condtion1>`, `<condition2>`, apply *substitution*.